# Java Array Integer manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

Cant seem to figure out why my array isnt outputting the correct value. The sum prints out as the first integer in the array. I wanted the sum of all the integers in the array. Any ideas what could be wrong? I attempted to convert the int to a string to be sent out.

```
  //Add values of Integers
  int i; int sum = 0; 
  for(i = 0; i < intarray.length; i++){  
      sum = sum + intarray[i];
  }

  String sumOut =  Integer.toString(sum);
  System.out.println( "to Client: " + sumOut);
  toclient.writeBytes("Sum = " +sumOut+'\n');
```

Comment: Where have you defined your array?

Comment: You can drop `String sumOut = ...` and use `sum` when printing, the `toString` method is called implicitly anyway.

Comment: does the array by chance have one value?

Comment: try to print out sum by using `System.out.println(sum);` immediately after the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks correct. Try printing out the contents of `intarray` to be sure what it contains. Also, how do you put values into `intarray`. Post some code to show us. Perhaps the array is not populated correctly.

Also, there is no need for the line

```
String sumOut =  Integer.toString(sum);
```

Java will convert an `int` to a `String` automatically when you use the `+` operator, for example:

```
System.out.println("to Client:" + sum);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem by its self. The problem was that when I used .toString  it only displayed the first park of the array. When I used just sum it displayed the total. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
package cruft;

/**
 * IntegerSum description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 7/25/12 8:14 PM
 */
public class IntegerSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] values = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            values[i] = Integer.valueOf(args[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("sum = %d", sum(values)));
    }

    public static int sum(int [] values) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int value : values) {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is essentially what the OP posted (other than not with a for-each loop). Unfortunately, the OP didn't post how he is initializing the array.

Comment: Not really - what's all that stuff about converting the sum to a String and whatnot?  I think mine is cleaner: the sum is encapsulated into a single method that can be called in other contexts, and it doesn't mingle summing and output.  These are the small details of which coding is made.

Comment: Granted, your design is cleaner. I was commenting on the logic. (And yes, I agree that there is no need to convert the int to a String explicitly...see my answer.)

Comment: The loop isn't written using the standard Java idiom; it fails to leverage the += operator.  That's a lot of commentary for such a small snippet.

Comment: Which is all syntactic sugar that still doesn't help answer the question of why the original code doesn't work in the first place. The problem is very likely in the array initialization.

Comment: Not syntactic sugar.  Writing it properly makes it easier to understand.  I didn't have to write out every entry in the array to know that this was correct. Writing clean code matters.

Comment: Agreed, this answer just rehashes the original code in a more pretty manner.

Comment: Apparently not - it actually works and produces the correct answer.  Since the OP is brand new to SO, I think it makes sense to demonstrate the proper initialization as well as show how to encapsulate things in methods.  It answers both questions.